# Seeding and calling a model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im calling this in my seed:

```
$prds = Products::find($id);
```

But I get the error:

```
Call to undefined method products::find()
```

Do you know where I'm going wrong? I do have a model called Products.

I renamed the class and it worked, although I would not like to rename it as it will screw up other things.

I believe the issue is, that the seed sits under:

```
seeds/products/product_a.php
```

Is there a way to access the model with the same name as the seed folder?

Answer (score 0):

Rename you model, and then repeat. I really don't know why, but often I found that just by renaming everything works. It is some kind of Laravel internal thing, maybe something with caching, but it can really make me frustrated ( after I spend two hours finding bugs in other places ).

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I don;t want to rename my class, I have updated original question with more details as to what I suspect the problem to be.

Comment: For the record, the "php artisan dump-autoload" command (composer dump-autoload in old laravel versions) will fix these problems without having to rename things.